# Область видимости JAVA

Tags: java

Как перебросить переменную с method1() в method2()?

Переменная не видна, так как она объявлена внутри метода, и на нее не существует жесткой ссылки. Иными словами, после выполнения метода переменная действительно стирается из памяти, что можно придумать?

Может есть вариант записать данные в временный файлик?

```
 public class Test1
        {
         ...
            @JavascriptInterface
            public String method1()
            {
                 String title = 1;
                 return title;
            }
         }
        public class Test2
        {
            public void method2()
            {
                 title //ошибка компиляции - переменная title не видна из этого блока кода
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Спасибо всем за внимание, вот ответ

```
 public class Test1
        {
         ...
            @JavascriptInterface
            public String method1()
            {
                 String title = 1;
                 SharedPreferences pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MyPref", MODE_PRIVATE);
                 SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
                 editor.putString("key_name", title);  // сохранение переменной
                 return title;
            }
         }
        public class Test2
        {
            public void method2()
            {
                 SharedPreferences pref = mContext.getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MyPref", MODE_PRIVATE);
                 String title = pref.getString("key_name", null);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Изучите, что такое свойства класса.

Comment: А этот код только на андроиде заработает?

Comment: @gil9red, где вы видите метку андройд?

Comment: @And, гугление `SharedPreferences` показывает ссылки на статьи по андроиду, и в вопросе нет соответствующей метки

Comment: @gil9red была метка, но её убрали

Comment: @And была метка, но её убрали

Answer (score 0):

Фигурные скобки задают область видения переменных. Это все к вопросу о стеке. Строчка

```
{ String title = "1" } // именно с кавычками, в вашем примере в String почему-то передается int
```

создаст ссылку на объект title в стеке. Объект будет доступен во всех вложенных уровнях { }, но как только закроется фигурная скобка, внутри которой создавался объект, он перестает быть доступен извне. Решить вопрос можно, например, создав объект как поле класса, то есть

```
public class Test1 {
       String title = "1";
       ...
       public String method1() {
       ... // Объект title будет здесь доступен
       }
       public class Test2 {
              public String method2() {
              ... // И здесь тоже
              }
       }
} // А вот здесь уже нет.
```

Comment: как раз сложность была в том что значение я получаю после @JavascriptInterface, и появлялось оно в методе, но постом выше я решил свою проблему и обошел область видимости